# How do I put different priors on different levels of a categorical variable in brms?

Tags: r, bayesian, prior

This is a just a coding query from a bayesian novice.

I have a model of this type:

```
response ~ pred + (1 | participant) + (1 | item)  # pred = {level1, level2, level3} [ref level = level1]
```

I’m using brms. I’d like to put different priors on the three levels of pred. Suppose these are the priors:

- intercept (level1): N ~ (1,1)
- effect of level2 relative to level1: N ~ (0,1)
- effect of level3 relative to level1: N ~ (-1,1)

I think I know how to set up the prior for level1; what I’m having trouble with is setting up the two different priors for level2 and level3. With my limited brms skills, this is the closest that I can get:

```
prior1 <- c(
prior(normal(1, 1), class = Intercept), # level1
prior(normal(0, 1), class = b, coef = weight) # prior for level 2, but specified as if there is no level3        
)
```

As you can see, I don’t know what to do with level3.

Apparently, it is possible to do this in Stan. (Unfortunately, I’m not proficient with Stan.) I’ve found the following code somewhere:

```
// prior specifications
b[1] ~ normal (0, 1);
b[2] ~ normal (-1, 1);
temp_Intercept ~ normal (1, 1)
```

In short, could someone possibly show me how to modify my brms code above so that I can set up separate priors for level2 and level3?

I’d be extremely grateful for any help with this.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the function *get_prior* from the brms package? It should display all the default priors and help you to select your own with the function *set_prior*.